# how to wait until the function has completed running (for loop) in node

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, for-loop, async-await

now the problem is the for loops just instantly loops everething
but i want it to wait before looping,
because evetime the loop runs it inserts data into the database **(and that takes time)**
so i want it to wait until the data has been inserted
and then increment the value of i and loop again

```
function insert_into_db(){
  for (let i = (howmuch/dueAmount);i>0;i--){

    clientChartArray = [aa1,bb1,(cc1*i),dd1,ee1,ff1,gg1,hh1] 
    PreviousChangesArray = [a1,b1,c1,d1,rowid]

    if(check_bal){  
      clientChart.run(`UPDATE hp2269 SET RD = ?, DL = ?, BA = ?, RA = ?  WHERE rowid = ? ;`,PreviousChangesArray,(err)=>{
        if(check_reminder == false){ 
          chartInsert(clientChartArray)
        }
      })
    }else{
      chartInsert (clientChartArray)
    }
    
  }  
}
```

***The problems it creates***

1. some insertions take longer than others
2. So the loop doesn't wait for them and goes on with the next insertion
3. So the entries **GET JUMBLED** and don't get inserted in order
4. The last inserted row is also used in a different function so it has to be accurate in order to get the desired result

i am actully really new to working with database so i dont know if i am doing any this wrong or if there is a fundumental problem in my code so please consider helping me out TQ

Answer (score 0):

In for loop you can wait the insertion to be finished.
Note this not work with loops that require a callback include forEach, map, filter, and reduce.

```
async function insert_into_db(){
          for (let i = (howmuch/dueAmount);i>0;i--){
        
            clientChartArray = [aa1,bb1,(cc1*i),dd1,ee1,ff1,gg1,hh1] 
            PreviousChangesArray = [a1,b1,c1,d1,rowid]
        
            if(check_bal){  
              let result = await clientChart.run(`UPDATE hp2269 SET RD = ?, DL = ?, BA = ?, RA = ?  WHERE rowid = ? ;`,PreviousChangesArray);
               if(check_reminder == false){ //or check result
                  await chartInsert(clientChartArray)
                  //do something
                }
            }else{
              await chartInsert (clientChartArray)
              // do something
            }
            
          }  
        }
```

Comment: it dosent work as it contains a call back functions ,, is it possible to just use a settimeout to delay the nexr loop

Comment: @docpinocchio i have update my answer.